# How does AWS convert an IPv6 address to an IPv4 address when whitelisting "My IP" address

Tags: amazon-web-services, ip, ipv6, ipv4

I recently had to whitelist my IP address in an AWS security group using the "My IP" option. It worked perfectly and displayed an IPv4 address, but when I looked up my IP address with Google I got an IPv6 address. I was curious how one server could see me as using an IPv4 address and another saw me using an IPv6 address? Is AWS translating the IPv6 address to an IPv4 address associated with my internet service provider?

Comment: Google supports IPv6, AWS doesn't (at least not for the console), so you're connecting via IPv4 and that's the IP you show up as to Amazon.

Comment: So when I try to connect to servers that do not support IPv6 does my router default to an IPv4 address? I guess I'm still confused as to how they can see different IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, you have both an IPv6 and IPv4 address right now. If you connect to an IPv4-only site like the AWS Console, you'll use the IPv4. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Dual_IP_stack_implementation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism etc.

Comment: @JeromeFroelich It's not the router which choose which kind of IP address to be using. When you access a website the browser choose which kind of IP address to be using. And if the server hasn't responded within about 100msec, a modern browser will try the other kind of IP address in parallel.

Comment: @ceejayoz, thank you very much! This makes a lot more sense!